# MS Access SQL Update table A with information of 2 other tables

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have 3 tables:

`````````
CLIENTS
```````
num_sect
nbr
address
city

IMPORTED
````````
nbr
address
city
sector
part

SECTOR
``````
num_sect
city
sector
part
`````````

I should sectorize the clients table, but only with the addresses imported using the sector that matches the addresses from imported.

`Update table clients.num_sect` that are inside `IMPORTED` with the

```
num_sect from sector.
```

I use this select to match all the lines where I should update Inside clients.

```
SELECT 
    c.num_sect, 
    c.nbr, 
    c.address, 
    c.num_abo, 
    imp.address, 
    imp.sector, 
    imp.part
FROM 
    clientes AS cli, imported as imp
WHERE 
    (c.address = imp.address and c.city = imp.city and c.nbr = imp.nbr)
```

But, I don't manage to update `num_sect` at clients from the selection/relation between them.

Thanks

SOLUTION:

UPDATE
(SELECT ab.num_sect, ab.city, ab.nbr, ab.address, ab.num_abo, aps.address, aps.part & aps.sector AS CD, aps.nbr FROM clinets AS ab, imported AS aps WHERE (aps.address = ab.address and aps.city = ab.city and ab.nbr = aps.nbr))  AS bla

INNER JOIN sector ON bla.CD=(sector.part & secteur.sector & right(sector.sector,1))

SET ab.num_sect = sector.num_sect;

I had a problem when comparing and concatenating a text with cint  (text = text & cint (text)) seems that it does not think that concatenating a text & cint(nbr) is a text.
I changed the approach, but now it works if the sector is only with 1 number (for now, it's fine for me).

Comment: Try `INNER JOIN` instead of WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it this way:

```
UPDATE (SELECT ab.num_sect, ab.city, ab.nbr, ab.address, ab.num_abo, aps.address, 
               aps.part & aps.sector AS CD, aps.nbr 
        FROM clinets AS ab, imported AS aps 
WHERE (aps.address = ab.address 
       and aps.city = ab.city 
       and ab.nbr = aps.nbr)) AS bla
INNER JOIN sector ON bla.CD=(sector.part & secteur.sector & right(sector.sector,1)) 
SET ab.num_sect = sector.num_sect;
```